# How do I create a custom pattern that users can implement with my interface?

Tags: c#, interface, factory-pattern

Much like the `IDisposible` pattern implements all kinds of properties and methods not necessarily (at least not that I can see) part of the interface.

Basically, when developers use my plugin interfaces I would like them to implement a cleaner pattern when they choose to do so and not all the `NotImplementedExcemption()`'s.

Comment: You can only do that by writing a Visual Studio extension (using Roslyn)

Comment: I was hoping it wasn't something like that and could be done through meta or flags...

Comment: Isn't the implementation of your interface a responsibility for the user?

Comment: You could provide a basic base class... but to say that's cleaner? :/

Comment: yes, but basic stuff when using VS's auto implementation like creating properties is a pain because it creates them to all throw an `NotImplementedExcemption()` inside get

Comment: Was just hoping that since I see other .net interfaces doing exactly this, that it would be possible for mine as well.

Comment: No; this is hard-coded.  See http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Features/ImplementInterface/CSharpImplementInterfaceService.cs,83

Comment: Doesn't ReSharper have some extra options?

Comment: Never fooled with ReSharper much, never agreed with the price point. (besides i'm speaking mainly for my 3rd party developers.). I just figured it seemed logical it would be something that could be done through flags in the interface definition or and abstract interface  implementation class. Surprised and not surprised that it isnt possible at the same time.